# Having trouble printing data using the criteria clause in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following code and the insertion is being done but the query in the query() is not printing the println that its suppose to.

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import roseindia.tutorial.hibernate.Insurance;

import com.Employee;

public class EmployeeEx 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Session session = null;

    try
    {       
        Transaction transaction = null; 

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session =sessionFactory.openSession();

        File f=new File("c:/Class/Employee1.txt") ;
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(f);

        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {               
            Employee em = new Employee();
            String line=scan.nextLine();            
            String empArray[]=line.split(" ");

            em.setId(Integer.parseInt(empArray[0]));
            em.setName(empArray[1]);
            em.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(empArray[2]));
            em.setManager(empArray[3]);
            session.save(em);
            transaction.commit();
        }   
  query();//calling the query method

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

finally
{
    session.flush();
    session.close();
}
}

public static void query()
{
    Session session = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    session =sessionFactory.openSession();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("manager", "Anurag"));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("salary", 1000));

    List emp = criteria.list();
    for(Iterator it = emp.iterator();it.hasNext();)
    {
        Employee em = (Employee) it.next();
        System.out.println("Id: " +em.getId());;
        System.out.println("Name: " +em.getName());
        System.out.println("Salary: " +em.getSalary());
        System.out.println("Manager: " +em.getManager());

    }
    session.close();
}

}
```

This is what is shown on the console:(The insertion is working fine)

```
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into EMPLOYEE1 (NAME, SALARY, MANAGER, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID0_, this_.NAME as NAME7_0_, this_.SALARY as SALARY7_0_,    this_.MANAGER as MANAGER7_0_ from EMPLOYEE1 this_ where this_.MANAGER like ? and this_.SALARY>? java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Can you please mention the exact problem? and correct the title as well? Fixing `Something` is quite difficult...

Comment: Sorry, I described my problem before the code

Answer (score 0):

The `query()` method is not being executed because you are not calling it.

Anyway, you can't call it from `main()` unless you make it `static`:

```
public static void query()
```

Only the `main()` method will be executed when you run a class, so after you have added `static` to the method signature of `query()`, add this line somewhere to your `main()` method:

```
query();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the `query()` method and it still doesn't print anything, then it means that your `emp` list is empty. Check your database if you have any record matching the restrictions of your query. If you do then check the contents of list `emp`.